# How to see the headers in a request while using Kong Ingress controller

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kong, kong-ingress

In any ingress controller like https://traefik.io/  there is usually a DEBUG mode to run. In this mode you can actually see the headers in the request which help in debugging.

However in https://docs.konghq.com/kubernetes-ingress-controller I am unable to find the same.

I have installed kong using [helm](https://github.com/Kong/charts) and it installs and runs fine.

I want to be able to see the headers in a request and I can't seem to find a way around it. There is no logging level defined in [values.yaml](https://github.com/Kong/charts/blob/main/charts/kong/values.yaml) file.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out you can enable debug mode by using the following environment variable. Add the following with other environment variables to get log in DEBUG mode

```yaml
env:
  log_level: debug
```

However, to see the values of requst headers and response you will need the following
[plugin](https://docs.konghq.com/hub/kong-inc/file-log/)

You might want to redirect it to `/dev/stdout` so it comes in output of kong logs.

Answer (score 0):

for debugging one can send a header; `Kong-Debug: 1` (see https://docs.konghq.com/gateway-oss/2.5.x/proxy/#evaluation-order ) and there is an upcoming change in 2.6 that might be helpful as well; see https://github.com/Kong/kong/pull/6744